# Dropdown not displaying for nav bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

My Web Designer is having trouble with his nav bar not displaying correctly. When hovering over a item with the `dropdown-items` class, a dropdown is supposed to appear with the items listed in the div. Instead, a block only appears with no items. The navbar is a React.JS component, and its being rendered in a parent container. I listed his html and css below.

Edit: Screenshot of the current result. It appears on hover but not under as it should in a list

Edit 2: It works in plain HTML w/ CSS but not React w/ CSS

[image]

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}


/*div{
    background:white;
}*/


/********* NavBar Section **********/

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #B597C3;
}


/* links inside the navigation bar */

.navbar li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: .625em 5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* color of links on hover */

.navbar a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.navbar a.active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}


/* Drop Down Items */

.dropdown-btn {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.0625em;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-items {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 10em;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.dropdown-items a {
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-items {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-btn">Clothes</a>
      <div class="dropdown-items">
        <a href="#">Item</a>
        <a href="#">Item</a>
        <a href="#">Item</a>
        <a href="#">Item</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Policies</li>
    <li>How To Rent</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It's appearing, but the link color is white. Is the background of your page white? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zZNZdX

Comment: yes, but on the page itsself its not appearing as such, let me post a screen capture

Comment: screenshot posted

Comment: Thanks. You were missing the `.navbar` parent that would make your code look like the screenshot. Edited for you.

Comment: My previous comment still stands. The menu works but you can't see white text on a white background. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dvNvmM

Comment: I used your CSS and it does not work on my app. Maybe this is a problem with React being rendered into one div ?

Comment: It works in plain HTML w/ CSS but not React w/ CSS